# CSV parse with IFS bash : choose ";" as the separator

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, ifs

I have a CSV with 130 cols and i need to do 3 csv with that. 
I'm looping with a while and IFS because i need to do someting with the vars on each row.

Here what i did :

```
while IFS=";" read [my 130 vars]
[what i do with the vars] 
done < file.csv
```

But i have a problem on some rows because the original csv i receive is like :

```
"Hi";"i";"got;a problem"
```

As you can see i have a problem with a ; in a value. And the IFS read it as the separation of two values.
So here is my question : is there a way to take ";" as the separator instead of just ; ?

Comment: did you try `IFS="\";\""`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i tried it and it didn't work :/

Comment: But what's the error message?

Comment: None, it just doesn't recognize anythin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf ("%s\n",$i)}}' file.csv
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
"Hi"
"i"
"got;a problem"
```

(I doubt if it's possible to achieve the desired result using `bash`, i.e. by manipulating `IFS`.)

Comment: That's it. I could not figure out the awk thing.. +1.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I'm not sure what the OP wants but I'd choose Perl over anything else for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

if you are OK with `perl`, then:

```
# cat version 
"Hi";"i";"got;a problem"

# perl -MText::ParseWords -n -l -e 'print $_ for parse_line(";", 1, $_);' version
"Hi"
"i"
"got;a problem"
```

I am sure there should be a way to achieve the same with `awk`

I could manage with `sed`:

```
# cat version | sed 's/;\("[^"]*"\)*/\n\1/g'
"Hi"
"i"
"got;a problem"
```

Comment: @devnull in fact yes now i have 15 reputation i can :)